# Data Fetching Technique

Tags: java, database

I would like have suggestion about to fetch data from database.
For example I have millions of data in database, and i want to display that in my web page as 10 rows per page using some programming language.
 
So what could be best way to do,

1. fetch all data and do pagination
2. or fetch limited data only.

Since in **first way data fetch** there could be chances of data manipulation, for example if i pooled out all data and displayed it, and user has changed some detail after data displayed. And for just a small change i need to get all millions of data again.

Whereas in second way of data fetch I need to connect always database for getting says 10 rows for each page.
Please do clarify my doubt

Comment: Fetch limited data AND do pagination.

Comment: It would obviously be a waste of time and memory to load millions of records only to display 10 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the simplest option is to just fetch the data as required, as suggested in [Per's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17003939/1711796). However, this may not yield the best performance (though if the application is not performance-critical, I wouldn't bother doing anything more).

Don't fetch millions of records if you're only going to display 10 of them. While an option worth considering (if your application has exclusive access to the data) is to have all your data loaded all the time and simply use the database more as a backup device, which you read from only when the application restarts, I think millions of rows is a bit much for this model.

Though caching could be a good option. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) has a list of caching algorithms. I'd probably suggest Least Recently Used.

Server-side caching is generally a decent consideration. **Danger** - An inefficient choice of data structures here (or lack of knowledge of how your application is used) could kill your application performance-wise.

Client-side caching could give a much faster application response time, especially in cases where there is high latency. Keep in mind that each user will have his/her own cache - this only works for certain applications.

On top of regular caching, for either of the above you can load let's say the 100 rows surrounding the 10 desired rows (assuming it is common for a user to go to the next / previous page, and this operation actually makes sense). 100 will be the number to play around with here - the ideal number greatly depends on how your application is used.

Taking Stack Overflow as an example, the most common (select) query is probably to display the list of new questions. These can all be cached (server-side), thus requiring no database query to get them.

### Useful note

For server-side caching, if your application has exclusive access to the data - whenever there are any changes, these will come through your application, so you can simply modify your local copy or clear the cache, no need to query the database to see if it changed.

For client-side caching, or if your application does **not** have exclusive access to the data - you can add versioning or a last-modified value somewhere in your database which you can query to check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

By all means do pagination using limited data fetches with query-level limitation/pagination. Loading all the data is not an option in my opinion, since it puts unnecessary strain on system resources, and is actually slightly more difficult to code.

Have a page variable, and use that to create parameters that you pass to the data query. How to actually do the query is quite database-dependent.

Simple example for MySQL could be a two-step query:

```
select count(*) from ... where ...
```

to get the number of possible results, then

```
select ... from ... where ... limit *offset*,*count*
```

where *count* is items-per-page, and *offset* is *count* times page-number. Do both queries for every page you query, to catch changes.